# How can you simulate double tapping space in python?

Tags: python, minecraft

I've been trying to code a Minecraft bot for a server that gives fly if you double tap space. However, I've been unable to find a way to click the space bar twice without leaving the initial click still active or too slow to activate the fly effect in the maximum 1.3 second time period. I've tried to find the string value for spacebar in other modules such as win32com and pyautogui but I've been unable to find them by myself or through the internet. I've also used `keyboard.release('space')` to simulating lifting your finger off from the spacebar, but this is too slow for the fly permission to be activated.

Code:

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con


import win32com.client as comclt
wsh = comclt.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
wsh.AppActivate("Crystal Client (v1.8.9-d9d3740/main)") 
wsh.SendKeys("{Esc}")
keyboard.press('space')
keyboard.press('space')
keyboard.press('space')
```

Comment: What about `keyboard.send('space', do_press=True, do_release=True)`

Comment: Yeah, this one is a winner.

Comment: Since it resolved your issue, I've added this as an answer so you can accept it and others will be able to find it later

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
for i in range(1):
    pyautogui.press('space')
```

or more simply, since PyAutoGUI lets you specify the number of presses you want to perform:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.press('space', presses=2)
```

Comment: For me, Minecraft is not registering any of the space clicks from pyautogui, but thank you for the help figuring out the id for space on pyautogui is.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for the keyboard module](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.send) suggest `send` as used for "single key (e.g. 'space') or multi-key, multi-step hotkey" and I would put this in the multi-step hotkey realm so replacing

```
keyboard.press()
```

with

```
keyboard.send()
```

allows you to take advantage of the built in press-and-release api

```
keyboard.send('space', do_press=True, do_release=True)
```